# How to monitor changes in firebird elegantly with delphi

Tags: delphi, logic, firebird

I'm writing a program that monitors changes in a firebird table and sends a blob (XML) from that table to a webservice. The problem is that at the moment I am sending it, it may change and it will be necessary to send it again. What is the best way to control this, since initially I had a field called SYNC (not to send forever in the thread) but I may update its status to true on my monitor at the time of a client change that I would set it to false and you would need to send it again.

Comment: keep a copy of the last sent blob. When you check the table again compare blobs and trigger event? Or am i missing something?

Comment: @whosrdaddy I don't think I can keep the copy of the blob because the monitor's idea is to make a massive select and with that it wouldn't be practical to check for each submission if in the meantime something has changed. For example, my monitor makes a select in the table bringing all the records that are with sync = 0. Now he starts sending them and later changes them all to sync = 1. I believe there is a better way to control what I'm saying, I just don't know which one. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: I get what you mean now, instead of using a flag, use a counter. When table is updated increase counter, when you send a blob decrease counter. you only need to send blobs that have counter > 0.

Comment: I believe there is a better way as Firebird can [monitor field changes](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/papers_presentations/Power_Firebird_events.pdf)

Comment: I've been looking at firebird post events. However the problem if for some reason the message doesn't arrive, he doesn't have a contingency for that. But your suggestion to use a count seems to work for me! Thank you you were awesome!

Comment: @RodrigoSouza As long as you have a valid connection to the database, you will be able to receive post events from it. Each time you connect to the database, send the current blob and set a local counter. Each time the event is received, increment the counter, and periodically check the counter for changes to know when to re-send the latest blob.

Comment: @RodrigoSouza Do not worry about that it is the first question, no need to apologize! We even have an automatic hint that it's your first question! (I edited out the apology, I did not touch the question itself)

Comment: All the changes are made and are visible only within contexts of transactions. Those transactions numbers you see in OIT/OAT values of db file header. So, when you form your XML bundle, you have to start a `SNAPSHOT READONLY` transaction, and mark your bundle with that tx ID. Also, for all the rows you dump into the XML you set the `SYNC` to this tx ID (see `current_transaction` SQL variable). When you change (update) some row - you clear (set `NULL`) `SYNC` from the trigger. Next time XML-making transaction is run it knows the updated row has to be sent again. What about deleted rows?

Comment: Potential trouble - if you do backup/restore cycle, the restore is technicalyl a creation of a new database, so all transaction numbers get reset. So if somewhere you would use a logic like "recorded transaction ID is a number less than current transaction's ID" (as compared to plain and dumb check "is `SYNC` column `NULL` or is there some just any number at all?") that logic would get faulted after B/R cycle